# mod_rewrite, multiple domain, virtualhost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, dns, virtualhost, mod-proxy

Here's what I'm trying to achieve :

1. redirection to 2 different application hosted for 2 different domain
2. redirect to https://
3. Not www-domain
4. Make sure trailing slash gets appended in-case user misses out.

Please note : 
It's a shared instance - so there's another application configured already.

**My Current solution configuration :**

```
# VirtualHost Listening on Port 80
123.123.1.1:80

# Original Configuration for Existing Application
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName 123.123.1.1:80
# Additional cluster configuration using Proxy ( mod_proxy ) & LoadBalancer
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName domain1.com

Redirect / https://domain1.com/app1/$1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
ServerName domain2.com

Redirect / https://domain2.com/app2/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

**Alternatives I have tried are :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain1.com/app1/$1


RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain2.com/app2/$1
```

Can someone please point out what additional configuration shall i do ?
**What is my mistake ?**

Answer (score 0):

Try using a condition to look for the domain then redirect based on the incoming domain being requested.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain1\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://domain1.com/app1/$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://domain2.com/app2/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately the solution did not work for me. It is going into infinite redirects. I have links like following in the application (https://m.domain.com/app1/login.html#pagename) and (https://m.domain.com/app1/test.html?id=1&id=2)